# Prove $f\in L^{1}(\lambda_2)$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(\mathbb{R}^{2},B(\mathbb{R}^{2}),\lambda_2)\; $   , where $\lambda_2$ is the Lebesgue measure for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

We define :

$$f(x,y) = ye^{-y^{2}(1+x^{2})}1_{(x,y)\,\in\,\mathbb{R}_+\times \,\mathbb{R}_+}$$

> Show that $f\in L^{1}(\lambda_2)$

** Edit : Without calulating the value of the integral **

I know that I have to bound f from above but with what ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially,
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{L^{1}(\lambda_{2})}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-y^{2}(1+x^{2})}dydx,
\end{align*}
a change of variable $u=y^{2}(1+x^{2})$ will do the computation in the inner integral.

**Edit:**

$e^{u}\geq\dfrac{1}{2}u^{2}$ for $u\geq 0$, so 
\begin{align*}
e^{-y^{2}(1+x^{2})}\leq\dfrac{2}{y^{4}(1+x^{2})^{2}},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-y^{2}(1+x^{2})}dydx\\
&\leq\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}ye^{-y^{2}(1+x^{2})}dydx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{y^{3}(1+x^{2})^{2}}dydx,
\end{align*}
and these integrals converge.

Comment: Sorry user I made a mistake check out the edit

Comment: @SkyLand77, somehow you need to compute at least something, or else things will just get unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: alright , thanks you ,  first I tried to bound with $\frac{1}{x^{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{y^{2}} $